# Discord.js can't read property send of undefined

Tags: discord.js

I've recently learned the basics of Discord.js and I tried to make my personal bot just for fun and one of the command in that bot is a !say command that lets me make the bot say whatever I want wherever I want but I'm always getting this error:

> Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content === `${prefix}say`) {
        const arguments = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
        const location = client.channels.chache.find(channel=>channel.id === arguments.shift());
        const whatToSay = arguments.slice(1);
        location.send(whatToSay);
        // !say (channel Id) blah blah blah
    }
});
```

I tried converting the arrow function into a normal function but it didn't work.

I tried replacing the arguments.shift() in the 4th line and it still didn't work.

I don't know where the mistake is

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of the properties in your code.

`client.channels.cache` and `arguments.shift`

Comment: i corrected ".cache" and it didn't work'
and i might have mispelled argument but it's still the same variable